# Filling ellipse with an arc using slider handler

Tags: java, graphics, 2d, ellipse

I was wondering how I can fill an arc inside of an ellipse with degrees as the user adjusts the slider values. I am stuck with the slider listener being in a different file from the arc and ellipse.

Comment: You'd start by calling `super.paintComponent` before doing any custom painting, you would then record the current slider value, calculate the range and call `repaint`

Comment: @madProgrammer Thanks!! So now if I have the arc made in a different file and the listener in a different one from that, is there any way I can do this or does the listener for the slider need to be in the same file as graphics? Sorry if unclear..

Comment: You would need some kind of model to link the two gether.  The listener would modify the model and the model would notify the renderer

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ok, here is what I have so far. [link]http://pastebin.com/ahSibYgQ Any suggestions as to why my listener for the slider isn't changing the shaded region of the ellipse? And don't mind the circle part..

Comment: Because you're creating a new instance of `ArcCanvas` in the `ChangeListener`, but it has no context to the screen, the `arcCanvas` that is on the screen and the one(s) you create in the `ChangeListener` have no relationship to each other.  Update the the instance of `arcCanvas` you created in the constructor...just like I did in my example...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ok, so I removed the ArcCanvas declarations in the constructor in the graphics file and implements methods similar to what you used for your slider listener into graphics file, but now in my listener when I try to set the angle of my arc but I can't because it is (presumably..) in the other file? Thank you again..sorry I don't completely follow.

Comment: I think you wanted to keep the arc in the constructor, only create it ONCE.  Then in the listener, you want to change the state of THIS instance.  This will mostly likely require you to have a method in your arc class that takes the new angel...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Last question..Is there anyway I can make my arc i declared in ArcCanvas.java to be accessible to JavaGraphics.java? This would allow me to use it in the listener..I believe

Comment: Just add a method to `ArcCanvas` that allows you to specify the extent you want and call that, then call repaint within that method, simpler and doesn't expose elements of your object that other's shouldn't have access to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Start by calling `super.paintComponent` before doing any custom painting, this will prevent any possible paint artifacts from been generated, which, while funky, aren't really nice. See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details
2. When the state of the slider changes, pass the current value to the component been used to paint the arc and call `reapint` on it
3. Be carefully mixing components with custom painting with other components (slider on arc pane), as it's very difficult to determine how to perform the custom painting if you don't want it covered by the other components...

[image: Arc]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class FillEllipse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FillEllipse();
    }

    public FillEllipse() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                final ArcPane arcPane = new ArcPane();
                final JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 360);
                slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                        int value = slider.getValue();
                        arcPane.setAngle(value);
                    }
                });
                slider.setValue(0);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(arcPane);
                frame.add(slider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ArcPane extends JPanel {

        private int angel;

        public ArcPane() {
        }

        public void setAngle(int angel) {

            this.angel = angel;
            repaint();

        }

        public int getAngel() {
            return angel;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            int diameter = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight());
            int x = (getWidth() - diameter) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - diameter) / 2;

            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.fillArc(x, y, diameter, diameter, 0, getAngel());
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```